# Pygame and IDEs -- source changes require python restart

Tags: python, scripting, ide, pygame

I can run my pygame project fine in either of the IDEs I use (Spyder and IEP), but then I try makes changes to some of the .py files and when I run the project again, the changes don't show up. I think this has something to do with the IDEs running .py files as scripts, but I can't figure out a good solution. I tried deleting the compiled files but the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Whenever you make a change to your .py files, you need to save them and restart the python session. You're saying that when you do that, nothing changes?

Comment: No, that works, but I was hoping to not have to restart the python session every time I make a change

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) function to update the running python instance with the updated files.

Comment: So do I call reload(MyModuleName) or reload(ModulesMyCodeUses)?

Comment: @zergylord You'd need to reload the modules that have changed since your last save.

Comment: anyway to just reset all modules? My project has alot of files in it :-/